# Simulink: Plot Timeseries in a scope/block to visualize data

Tags: matlab, scope, time-series, data-visualization, simulink

I have a Simulink block that calls a user-defined function. This function calls another function: thingspeakread.m (provided by the [ThingSpeak Official Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52244-thingspeak-support-toolbox)).

From here, I want two outcomes. Data (numeric type, vector), and timestamps (strings, vector).

```
[data,timestamps] = thingSpeakRead(___)
```

Now, I'm able to get the values of "Data" into a Scope without much of an issue (using coder.extrinsic('thingSpeakRead') and preallocating the variable to store such points). The issue I have is this: I need to make more sense of the data visualization, and for that purpose, I need to plot this "Data" against the information displayed in the timestamps vector. The timestamps varies per minute only.

What I'll try to do, but doesn't satisfies me a lot:

- Convert the timestamp into a numeric value using datenum() using the format for 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS'

This option sends back a huge number (which can be used to plot Data vs. Time indeed, but it doesn't look 'good' because the number is just too big and I don't like it).

I have thought about these too:

- Convert date to Julian Date type.
- Convert Hours, Minutes and Seconds into 3 different arrays.

But I don't see that getting me where I want (which is to plot Data vs. Time, being able to spot easily that the numbers displayed for "Time" are corresponding to an specific HH:MM:SS of a day).

Is there anything you can guys suggest, please? Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit 1: Can I use something like [datetick()](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) in Simulink?

Comment: Can you use MATLAB Function block to call into MATLAB where you can write any MATLAB code to plot your data? You would need to declare you function as extrinsic in MATLAB Function block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing with converting to `datenum` is the only way to pass the *"dates"* down a Simulink signal.

There's no mechanism to display the time series, with dates displayed on the x-axis, without writing custom code.

If you don't need to display the time series as the simulation is running then just dump it to a mat file in your existing code, and generate the plot during post-processing.

If you want it to display as the simulation is running then you'll need to write a custom display block.  This should be done as a `Level-2 M-Code S-Function`, but could be done using a `MATLAB Function` block.  Either way you would input the `datenum` into the block and then convert the `datenum` back to a date - using something like `datetime` before generating the visualization, or afterwards using `datetick`.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this Phil. Sorry for sounding so lazy, but, can you share here a tutorial on how to build a Level-2 S-function?

Comment: Best starting point is to type `sfundemos` at the MATLAB command line and navigate to the Level-2 M-Code examples.  There aren't any specific demos for visualization, but they'll show how to get data into the S-Function, and from there it's just a matter of putting it into a MATLAB figure window.

Comment: Thank you a lot Phil. Yes, I dug into it, saw the templates and the examples. Will start from there.